# Finding the common columns when comparing two rows in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the below structure. I want to get the column numbers which has the same value (for a specific value) when i compare two rows.

```
1 1 0 1 1
0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 1
```

So for example when I use the above sample df to compare two rows to get the columns which has 1 in it, I should get col(1) and col(3) when I compare row(0) and row(1). Similarly, when I compare row(1) and row(2), I should get col(1). I want to know if there is a more efficient solution in python.

NB: I want only the matching column numbers and also I will specify the rows to compare.

Comment: Do you want the column number, or the whole column in return?

Comment: Do you want all pairwise comparisons or will you specify which rows to compare?

Comment: I will specify which two rows to compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(1, 0.2, (2, 10000)))
```

It will be a binary matrix of size 2x10000.

```
np.where((df.iloc[0] * df.iloc[1]))
```

Or,

```
np.where((df.iloc[0]) & (df.iloc[1]))
```

returns the columns that have 1s in both rows. Multiplication seems to be faster:

```
%timeit np.where((df.iloc[0]) & (df.iloc[1]))
1000 loops, best of 3: 400 µs per loop

%timeit np.where((df.iloc[0] * df.iloc[1]))
1000 loops, best of 3: 269 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function. You can modify it as needed, depending on how you represent your data. I'm assuming a list of lists:

```
df = [[1,1,0,1,1],
      [0,1,0,1,0],
      [0,1,0,0,1],
      [1,0,0,0,1],
      [0,0,0,0,0],
      [1,0,0,0,1]]

def compare_rows(df,row1,row2):
    """Returns the column numbers in which both rows contain 1's"""
    column_numbers = []
    for i,_ in enumerate(df[0]):
        if (df[row1][i] == 1) and (df[row2][i] ==1):
            column_numbers.append(i)
    return column_numbers
```

`compare_rows(df,0,1)` produces the output:

`[1,3]`